# How to solve three equations with four unknowns iteratively?

Tags: equation-solving

I have three equations of the form

$\quad \eta = f(N1L, N2L)$

$\quad N1L = g(\eta, R)$

$\quad N2L = h(\eta, R)$

I want to eliminate $\eta$, so that I can get $N1L$ and $N2L$ for a range of $R$.

I copied my short program bellow (which can't be solved by the methods I know.)
I really appreciate any help.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
T = 25 + 273.15;                     
k = 1.3806488*10^-23;      
theta = Degree 10;              
gama = 0.07199;            
Psat1 = 3.168*10^3;         
PL = 101.325*10^3;                       
vLinf = (1/997.0479)*18.015/1000;   
L = 0.45;              
Vcontainer = L^3;      
N1total = 3.049*10^27;
N1 = N1total/Vcontainer;                                   
N2total = 3.67*10^22;           
N2 = N2total/Vcontainer;                                  
qc = 1.22*10^8;
w = 50*10^-6; 
alfa = Degree 45;
KH = 1639.34*10^5/(10^3*6.02*10^23);   

Vv[R_] := (Pi*R^3/3)*(2 - 
     3*Sin[theta - alfa] + (Sin[
        theta - alfa])^3 + (Cos[theta - alfa])^3/Tan[alfa]);
Asv[R_] := Pi*R^2*(Cos[theta - alfa])^2/Tan[alfa];
Alv[R_] := 2*Pi*R^2*(1 - Sin[theta - alfa]);
H[R_] := R*(1 - Sin[theta - alfa] + Cos[theta - alfa]/Tan[alfa]);

(******************This is where my qyestion is:*******************************)

N1L[R_] := N1 - qc*(etha[R]*Psat1*Vv[R]/(k*T));     
N2L[R_] := N2/(1 + qc*PL*Vv[R]/((N1L[R]*PL/KH)*k*T));     
etha[R_] := Exp[vLinf*(PL - Psat1)/(k*T) - N2L[R]/N1L[R]];

Rc[R_] := 2*gama/(etha*Psat1 + PL*(N2L[R]/(N1L[R]*PL/KH)) - PL);    
B[R_] := qc*(-2*gama * Vv[R]/Rc[R] + 
      gama*(Asv[R]* Cos [Degree (theta)] + Alv[R])) + 
   N1total*k*T*(N2/N1 - N2L[R]/N1L[R]) + 
   N2total*k*T*
    Log[N1*k*T/(N1*k*T - qc*etha*Psat1*Vv[R] + qc*Vv[R]*KH)];

t1 = Table[{ R*10^6, Rc[R]*10^6}, {R, 10^-6, 10^-5, 10^-7}];
ListPlot[t1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["R(micrometer)", "Graphics", FontSize -> 13], 
   Style["Rc (micrometer)", "Graphics", FontSize -> 13]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, TicksStyle -> Directive[12]]
```

Comment: In principle, plug the `N1L` expression into `N2L`, then plug both into the `etha` equation so that you have a single equation in the unknown `etha`(with `R` as a parameter), then use `FindRoot`. In practice your numbers are very large ( `vLinf*(PL - Psat1)/(k*T) ~10^20 ` ) so you need to work on normlising things to avoid numeric overflow .

Answer (score 1):

I would not use functions.  I would treat your equations as expressions and manipulate them:

```
etharule = etha -> Exp[vLinf*(PL - Psat1)/(k*T) - N2L/N1L];

n1leqn = N1L == N1 - qc*(etha*Psat1*Vv[R]/(k*T));

n2eqn = N2L == N2/(1 + qc*PL*Vv[R]/((N1L*PL/KH)*k*T));

eqnsToSolve = {n2eqn, n1leqn} /. etharule;
```

Now you can solve the equations for each value of `R` (two equations, two unknowns) 
You can plot a curve by varying `R` and resolving at each step.  Also, George2079 is right, you will need to rescale your equations because you will overflow *Mathematica* with such large numbers.